# How to get properties to return in the body of an Authenticate request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I'm setting up a new ASP.NET API project, copying the basics from an existing project. For authentication, I've set up a class that inherits from `OpenIdConnectServerProvider`. The authentication is working fine in `HandleTokenRequest()`. But in addition to the `access_token`, I want to return some additional data for the client on a successful login. Copying from the existing project, I did the following in `HandleTokenRequest()`:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"userId", user.UserId.ToString()},
    {"userTypeId", ((int) user.Type).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}
};
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties(data);
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), properties, context.Scheme.Name);
context.Validate(ticket);
```

For some reason, however, I'm not getting back the `userId` and `userTypeId` in the response body. Here's what I get in the response:

```
{
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "access_token":"CfDJ...etc",
  "expires_in":1209600
}
```

There's obviously some secret switch I'm missing that will inject the `AuthenticationProperties` into the response body. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `ApplyTokenResponse` in the `OpenIdConnectServerProvider` to explicitly add the properties. I think they’re not returned by default (they’re just present for reference, as needed).

```
public override Task ApplyTokenResponse(ApplyTokenResponseContext context)
{
    if (context.Ticket != null)
    {
        foreach (var property in context.Ticket.Properties.Items)
        {
            context.Response.AddParameter(property.Key, property.Value);
        }
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```